# XPath command to get only a specific element data and not others

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xpath-2.0, domxpath

Suppose I have an XML file -

```
<Cars>
            <Year> 2021 </Year>
            <Model>
                <Name> Porsche 911 </Name>
                <Year> 2020 </Year>
            </Model>
            <Model>
                <Name> Porsche 911 </Name>
                <Year> 2019 </Year>
            </Model>
            <Model>
                <Name> Porsche Cayenne </Name>
                <Year> 2019 </Year>
            </Model>
</Cars>
```

Now I want to extract the Year **2021** which is not the Year of that particular model but the date when this XML was written (It is the outer one)

But to do that.. due to restraints on the path not being hardcoded, I was using `//Year//text()` but it gives out the output as `[2021,2020,2019,2019]`. I don't want that because if the order is changed, the index changes and that would create a problem.

Please help with a XPath command where I can exclude the inner **Year** tags and only use the outer one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one to get only outer Year

```
//Year[not(preceding-sibling::Name)]/text()
```

If required `Year` node (nodes) is always direct child of `Cars` then

```
//Cars/Year/text()
```

should also be OK

Comment: Depending on how `Cars` varies over time and other occurrences, maybe just `/Cars/Year[1]/text()` would suffice.

Comment: @kjhughes yes. I assumed that spaces between `Cars` and `Year` in provided XML sample might mean that there are more "interim" nodes

Comment: @kjhughes but what if that year is mentioned at the end and not at the top. I can't hardcode it

Comment: @Mud: In your posted example XML, `Year` appears multiple times as a direct child of `Cars`.  What is the distinguishing, invariant characteristic of the particular `Year` that you want? (If you intended your indentation to represent a child relationship, the XML itself belies that intention.  In that case, fix the XML to reflect the actual hierarchy, and indent properly.)

Comment: One ```Year``` is a direct child of Cars whereas the other ```Year```s are children of Model.

Yeah sorry my bad, there was an error in the representation I've corrected it now

Comment: If there's ever only a single `Year` child of `Cars`, and that's the `Year` element whose text you want, then the solution is simple: `/Cars/Year/text()`.